# SSO SAML with React Native (EXPO)

Tags: react-native, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have a task on my hands, but not absolutely sure how to start on this.

Hopefully community can provide some guidance.

I need to integrate react-native mobile app with SAML thus enabling app to leverage SSO.

At the moment business have a desktop implementation which goes like this:

1. user goes to http://subdomain.example.com/
2. gets redirected to identity provider (IdP)
3. signs in at identity provider
4. gets redirected back to http://example.com
5. uses example.com SaaS as signed user.

I imagine a similar approach could be done for react-native app?

Or when it comes to SAML integration with react-native different pattern must be used?

Are there potentially 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: I did, I followed what Auth0 is doing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evRIdbdSBgA&index=1&list=PL5p2lFNBdijmT8kRyll_agTJ_HRI04Ynk&t=4m30s standard implementation. It works for now, replicates how our web is done. Later on moving to AWS Cognito, similar implementation though.

Comment: That video is unavailable, is there an updated link?

Comment: @rock3t video is unavailable. This video is private.

Comment: Sorry gents that wasn't my video, seems to be taken offline.

Comment: How were you able to accomplish this @rock3t? Can you please explain or at least refer to some docs or resources other than the deleted video?

Comment: Bit of a necro, but to anyone who came here looking for the same thing I did, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69671161/how-do-i-use-saml-to-authenticate-a-user-in-firebase-under-react-native-expo/69671162#69671162) might be helpful.