# How do I use SAML to authenticate a user in Firebase under React Native + Expo

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, expo, saml

I couldn't find any questions (or answers) on SO or elsewhere when I was looking for a way to add SAML single-sign-on to the React Native app I'm working on, so here I am: see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start off I tried following [Google's documentation for this](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#redirect) but after a lot of messing about with WebViews and trying to lie to the DOM, I found out that it simply wasn't supported on react native (something that would have been nice to see in the docs a bit more obviously). Eventually I settled on adapting those instructions (follow the [first](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#before_you_begin) and [second](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml#configuring_the_provider) sections) using a dummy webpage opened by Expo's `WebBrowser` to act as a middle man. This is needed because firebase enforces https(s): for the protocol when making a call to `signInWithRedirect` or `signInWithPopup` but react native will send a protocol of about: or something similar when trying the call in JavaScript or even nested in a WebView, expo however calls the native browser and thus works on an http(s) protocol while still allowing information to be passed back into the app. There may be a way to do this using react native's webview, but I couldn't find anything remotely similar.

This preface leads me to the solution I came up with, which was merged into [Expo's examples](https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-firebase-saml-login).

Obviously use this at your own risk, I am no expert on cybersecurity but even I know there are more than a few vectors for attack here.